# Fresh Install - Redirect loop on cart.php/admin.php

Tags: php, x-cart

I've just installed X-Cart (5.2.4) to a Nitrous.io box for a quick play around and after what appears to be a textbook installation, any attempt to view the front or back end of the website results in an infinite loop.

The permissions appear to be correct, based on the installation not flagging anything and setting the folder permissions based on the installation complete page.

Nothing appears in the error_log and none of the xcart/var/log files are being populated (asides from the installation log.)

Only thing I can think of is that I'm using Nitrous.io which appears to be forwarding requests using the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST header. I applied the fix as per the link below:

https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Redirect_Loop_Error

Any idea's?

Thanks

Gav

Answer (score 0):

Just replied on the same topic here: http://forum.x-cart.com/showthread.php?t=71958

Anyway, are you sure that your actual domain name is specified in the etc/config.php file?